# How Export an Editable Chart with content to PPT and Excel

Tags: d3.js, chart.js

I have a work request to export an editable chart to power point.

I have seen this type of implementation in myworkday.com website, where when you click a button, the chart is exported to power-point.

now the power-point gets opened. See the below image.

If you check below, i have edited an group, please let us know if any chart library is there with editable export facility.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use PptxGenJS JavaScript library which will satisfy your requirements.[PptxGenJS](https://github.com/gitbrent/PptxGenJS)